# django восстановление пароля, проверить введённую пользователем почту email

Tags: python, django

> На странице для сброса пароля через почту, я хочу проверить какую почту ввёл пользователь мне ВАЖНО что бы она заканчивалась на @yandex.ru

- views.py

  ```
   class UserForgotPasswordView(SuccessMessageMixin, PasswordResetView):
       """
       Представление по сбросу пароля по почте
       """

       form_class = UserForgotPasswordForm
       template_name = 'registeruser/user_password_reset.html'
       success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
       success_message = 'Письмо с инструкцией по восстановлению пароля отправлена на ваш email'
       subject_template_name = 'registeruser/email/password_subject_reset_mail.txt'
       email_template_name = 'registeruser/email/password_reset_mail.html'

       def get_context_data(self, **kwargs): 
           context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
           context['title'] = 'Запрос на восстановление пароля'
           return context

   class UserPasswordResetConfirmView(SuccessMessageMixin, PasswordResetConfirmView):
       """
       Представление установки нового пароля
       """

       form_class = UserSetNewPasswordForm
       template_name = 'registeruser/user_password_set_new.html'
       success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
       success_message = 'Пароль успешно изменен. Можете авторизоваться на сайте.'

       def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
           context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
           context['title'] = 'Установить новый пароль'
           return context
  ```
- forms.py

  ```
   class UserForgotPasswordForm(PasswordResetForm):
       """
       Запрос на восстановление пароля
       """
       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           """
           Обновление стилей формы
           """
           super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
           for field in self.fields:
               self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
               'class': 'form-control',
               'autocomplete': 'off'
           })


   class UserSetNewPasswordForm(SetPasswordForm):
       """
       Изменение пароля пользователя после подтверждения
       """
       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           """
           Обновление стилей формы
           """
           super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
           for field in self.fields:
               self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
               'class': 'form-control',
               'autocomplete': 'off'
           })
  ```
- urls.py

  ```
   urlpatterns = [
       path('password-reset/', UserForgotPasswordView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
       path('set-new-password/<uidb64>/<token>/', UserPasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
   ]
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Внутри формы можешь определить clean для общих проверок или для определенного поля в формате `clean_{field_name}` - типо `def clean_email(self)`  и там провести нужную проверку, оно вызовется «само».
Значение твоих полей будут в self.cleaned_data

Вместо split по "@" можно проверить через endswith